# Trying to get input for a file to delete?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make a Win32 console program in C++ where a user can input a specific file/file location and press enter to have it deleted. For some reason, I get an error saying, "argument of type int is incompatible with parameter of type const char". No idea what this means or where to start.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    cout << "Input the directory of the file to delete: \n";

    int filesinput;
    cin >> filesinput;


    if (remove(filesinput;) != 0) // error is here
        perror("Error deleting file");
    else
        puts("File successfully deleted");

    system("pause");
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to store a file name in an `int`?

Comment: Make `fileinput` a `std::string` and remove the ; in `remove()`.

Comment: Why are you using C++ I/O for input and C I/O for (some) output?

Comment: @ChristianHackl C syntax is supported in C++

Comment: @nicomp It is, but mixing the two often comes with performance penalties.

Comment: @nicomp: You don't say? :)

Comment: @ChristianHackl :) , Sorry,  I couldn't resist!